# Intermittent connection issues on Netgear EX6150 Extender in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04

I'm having intermittent connection issues involving a Netgear EX6150 AC1200 WiFi Range Extender on Ubuntu 18.04 with my laptop's Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac wifi modem.

My laptop is generally the only connection on the Extender.   My laptop works fine connecting to my other wifi modems, and the connection to my EX6150 extender is generally great, except that about once every hour or three the connection stalls.  It seems like the connection is still there to some degree, however, because if I'm downloading something it keeps downloading at a high bitrate, but if I try to load a new webpage, like some google search query, it will stall out and either load the page very slowly or or just stop all together.

The only solution I have found is to restart the connection with:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And that seems to reset everything enough between my laptop and my extender to make things work again.  I know some routers get gridlocked with too much traffic sometimes, but since I'm the only one on this extender and I generally don't seem to have all that many connections to it when it stalls, I'm not sure why there would be gridlock.

Has anyone else ever run into this issue before?  Are there other ways to get computers to snap out of it than to simply reconnect?

**UPDATE**

After running though a bunch of different extenders, I bought a mesh network and everything works great now, so it was probably just problems with my router equipment capabilities and not a software/ubuntu issue.

Comment: What version firmware in the EX6150? Configured as access point, repeater, or fastlane? How far away is the EX6150 from the main router?

Comment: @heynnema I'm currently using Firmware Version 1.0.0.42, but I've also tried 1.0.0.34, 1.0.0.16, and 1.0.0.14.  I've tried doing a factory reset.  I've used it as regular repeater and with the fastlane. The issue seems to persist in all cases.  The extender is about 30 ft from the main router and has relatively good line of sight.  The connection from the extender to both my machine and to the main router seems fine and they both generally produce green lights on the extender indicating good connections.

Comment: You seem to have a v1 repeater. I have a v2. If you setup your extender as a dual-band repeater, without fastlane, try connecting to either 2.4G or 5G, and see if there's any difference, or if the problem occurs on both.

Answer (score 1):

A WiFi Wireless Extender basically uses the maximum speed of your wireless extension ***at the point the Wireless Extender is installed***.

That means: a Wireless extender will pick up the existing WiFi signal where it is installed and re-broadcast it from there.

So if your original is in the basement (-1) and you installed the WiFi Wireless Extender in your bedroom (+2) it will rebroadcast the weak signal it is receiving on +2. So to improve performance:

1. move the Wireless extender to the ground floor (0) or the first floor (+1)

   **OR**
2. Get a Wireless Access Point instead of a Wireless Extender and use a decent network cable or PowerLine Adapter to re-broadcast a 1Gbps or 100-333Mbps connection respectively.

*This also makes this question off-topic on Ask Ubuntu as it has no relation to Ubuntu itself.*